# Architecture for capturing result of webservice and send result to other webservices

Tags: c#, design-patterns, architecture

I am developing an application in C#. 
I am calling a webservice (lets call this WS1) and I want the result to be send to 1 or more other (external) webservices (eg WS2 and WS3).

In case one of the receiving webservices (for example WS2) is down, I want to make sure this call is not lost and is tried again at a later time.

What is a good architecure to achieve this?
Does anyone have a link to an online document where an architecture like this is described?

Comment: This question is both *too broad* and *off-topic* (for the reason Andreas described).

Comment: The retry req means you need a queue (list of workitems). Your own or one in the cloud, depending on scale etc.

Answer (score 1):

Some question you might need to ask before you dig into the architecture. I assume that WS1 and WS2 are both owned by you/your team.

1. How long do you want to wait for WS2 to be back up and running once it is down?
2. What is the response time expectation from WS1 and WS2?
3. Are there any other downstream service that is consuming WS1 and if that service has an SLA / response time expectation?
4. How does WS1 expect to consume the response from WS2?

In short an event driven approach looks the best fit here. i.e. you can have a queue in between WS1 and WS2 such that WS1 posts a message into the Request Queue, WS2 picks it up when ready and places the response in to a Response Queue from where WS1 can read it.
Example. [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/implementing-enterprise-integration-patterns-with-aws-messaging-services-point-to-point-channels/) and [Azure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt829271.aspx).

This may or may not work based on how you may answer the previous queries. Sometimes it is better to use a regular REST based call with a retry strategy (Example [exponential back off](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/api-retries.html) strategy). With this you may also be able to get a faster feedback on failures. One may choose this if answers for the above questions are

1. If the wait time is short, i.e. in terms of seconds
2. There is an expectation of really fast response time. In which case it is better to report a failure immediately than wait on it.
3. If there are downstream applications that has a synchronous dependency on WS1 hence WS1 cannot endlessly wait for WS2 to process the request
4. There isn't a predicable response channel from WS2

On a note, if you use a event based architecture then WS2 may not be a web service anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

I think, you might need a Load Balancer for your web service architecture.
You can use a raspberry pi or any pc, install linux and run nginx as load balancer, like what im currently doing.

You can read more at
[How to configure Nginx as Load Balancer](https://www.booleanworld.com/configure-nginx-load-balancer/)

Answer (score -3):

If I understand correctly you are looking to have an event driven architecture where requests can be replayed.

SNS is similar to SQS in decoupling your architecture and is either a topic or a queue. The difference is whether you want to poll or push these requests.

SNS use case:
You will push messages to a SNS topic where it will store the message for a max of 14 days. You can then schedule the SNS topic to deliver messages to a rest endpoint. If it fails you can handle that by putting the message on a DLQ (dead letter queue). If it succeeds the message will be removed from the topic.

SQS use case:
You will push messages to a SNS topic where it will store the message for a max of 14 days. You then poll the queue for events if the event processes remove it from the queue. Otherwise you can use the DLQ strategy or just leave the message on the queue.

Some good reading is [SNS Fanout strategies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/sns-common-scenarios.html)

Comment: Very quickly this answer goes to acronyms for one specific product, rather than anything about architecture.